# как сделать фоновый рисунок дива двухцветным

Tags: css, вёрстка

Допустим левая часть дива должна иметь красный цвет, а правая - синий.
 Как это сделать? В идеях было только поставить на красный див картинку с синим фоном и поместить текст поверх этого всего в див, который имеет z значение большее чем картинка. Я верстаю резиновую страницу, это не подходит. Еще варианты?

Comment: Вот тут, скорее всего, есть решение вашей проблемы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно не добавлять второй див, а использовать градиент:

```
background: rgb(255,0,0);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(121,9,9,1) 50%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 50%);
```

Есть даже отличный генератор градиентов
https://cssgradient.io

Answer (score -1):

Использовал два дива разных цветов, каждый из которых заполнял левую и, соответственно, правую часть родительского дива на 50%. Они стали находится на одной линии, когда я добавил им float:left/right

Comment: Ответы лучше давать с кодом, тогда минусовать не будут

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: Нет, тут видимо минусанули за сам подход. Ну, реально же 2020 на дворе))